# Finding a directory name or a folder name in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I just want to know if there's a way that I can get the name of the directory or a folder.

So for example I have these folders in my directory

test1_ew
test2_ter
test3_ew

So I just want to get the folders that have "_ew" on their names.
So basically I want to check all the folder names in my current directory if there's a _ew on their names.

If such folder(s) exist, I would like to run an executable file inside the folder(s).

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: You need to add a few more specifics. What language are you using?

Comment: I've added the CMD tag for you and added the full requirements of your question to make it clear for others.

Comment: Thank you bro, this is also my first time to use SO

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `IF EXIST` if the text you are looking for will not change?

Here's an example:

```
C:\Scripts>for /f %a in ('dir c:\scripts\*s* /b /A:D') do echo %a
C:\Scripts>echo sccm
sccm
C:\Scripts>echo Test
Test
C:\Scripts>echo updates
updates
```

-Edit to add `IF EXIST`

```
C:\Scripts>for /f %a in ('dir c:\scripts\*s* /b /A:D') do if exist %a echo YES
C:\Scripts>if exist sccm echo YES
YES
C:\Scripts>if exist Test echo YES
YES
C:\Scripts>if exist updates echo YES
YES
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Attribute switch `/A:` with the `DIR` command to specify you only want to look for a directory and use a wildcard for the directory name:

```
DIR C:\FOLDER\*_ew /B /A:D
```

You could also send this to a text file, for example on your desktop, like so:

```
DIR C:\FOLDER\*_ew /B /A:D > %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\TEST_OUTOUT.txt
```

note that if any of the paths used have spaces you will need to wrap them in quotation marks.

Comment: I need some more help. I want that if I found a folder that containing _ew on their name. I want to have a If statement that, if found _ew then will open a executable file. I'm sorry this is my first encounter batch scripts
What I have now is this one

for /d /r "E:\tester" %%i in (*.*) do if /i "%%~nxi"=="ew" set "folderpath=%%i" 
(
echo %folderpath%
)

Comment: Will all of the _ew directories have an exe file in them? and what will the exe file be called? - or do you mean that if the directory exists that you want to a run a separate exe file saved somewhere else?

Comment: No, I think im totally lost now. Give me a moment. Sorry

Comment: Actually bro, I have this script that finding a Stuck files with "FALSE" string with their names (not in their file names or directory name) STRING name. I already did this and, what I want is, all those have "FALSE" string on their names is I want to get and move them into another directory and ALL THOSE FILES is have different extensions. I hope you'll get my point.

Comment: Not really - I'm not sure what you mean when you say that "FALSE" is in their `String` name and not in their actual filename?

Comment: Something like this If I searched them in command line. This is the output.. FALSE "C:\tester\etcetc\gjasdsdasd.txt"

Comment: Have you tried something like `IF EXIST C:\tester\etcetc\gjasdsdasd.txt MOVE C:\tester\etcetc\gjasdsdasd.txt C:\tester\etcetc\other_folder\gjasdsdasd.txt`

Comment: I already tried that one and yes it's working. But what I want to do is, call the FALSE string and get the file that have FALSE string and move it.

Comment: @SierraOscar What is the meaning of `/A:D` and when it appear separately like `/A` or `/D` and `/A:D` or `/A-D` please ?

Comment: @ChamindaBandara [SS64 - DIR](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)